# Access nested list element, depth known in runtime

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I want to write to an element in a nested list named `foo`, but the nesting depth and indexes is only known at runtime, in a (non-nested!) list variable named `indexes`.

Examples:

If `indexes` is `[4]`, I want `foo[4]`.

If `indexes` is `[4,7]`, I want `foo[4][7]`.

If `indexes` is `[4,7,3]`, I want `foo[4][7][3]`.

What I could think of is to put together the command string (`"foo[4][7][3]"` in the last example), then call `eval`. 
That would be `eval("foo["+']['.join([str(n) for n in indexes])+']')`.

That works, and is short enough, but I was hoping for a simpler, more pythonic way.

Does anyone know any alternatives?

Is there a way to *not* treat the empty list separately? As in:

If `indexes` is `[]`, I want the whole `foo`.

This needs an `if` in the `eval` solution.

EDIT: I need to **write to**, not read from, the element. I don't think either of the two existing answers, nor the answers to the indicated duplicate, can be used for writing. Apologies for misleading.

Comment: don't use `eval`, use `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: `result = foo; for index in indexes: result = result[index]; return result`? No `eval`uating, literal or otherwise, and treats the empty `indexes` how you want.

Comment: @jonrsharpe even better!! I had written a recursive method, but it's not worth it.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: I *knew* I had answered this before, but could not find it in my answer list!

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I could've sworn I had one somewhere too, with a simple loop like Jon describes, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: `ast.literal_eval()` doesn't support variable access or subscription. Only literals are supported (so list displays, strings, integers, etc.)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I know. that was just a generic comment about non using `eval`. I didn't fully read the question.

Comment: Editing is merely assigning to the last key. So use `indexes[:-1]` to get to the last, then use `result[indexes[-1]] = value` to assign to that last place.

Comment: @Martijn probably need to work out what needs to happen in the `[]` case...

Comment: @JonClements: already covered in my update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`reduce()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
from functools import reduce  # Python 3 forward compatibility
import operator

def access(lst, indexes):
    return reduce(operator.getitem, indexes, lst)
```

You *could* use `list.__getitem__` instead of [`operator.getitem`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.getitem), but then you limit the application to list objects only (it wouldn't work for tuples or dictionaries, the latter with keys rather than integer indices).

This repeatedly applies the indices, in order, to the previous result (starting the original list). This meets all your criteria, including the empty-list case:

```
>>> foo = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'spam', 'eggs', 'ham', 'monty', ['alpha', 'beta', 'delta', 'gamma']]]
>>> access(foo, [])
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'spam', 'eggs', 'ham', 'monty', ['alpha', 'beta', 'delta', 'gamma']]]
>>> access(foo, [4])
['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'spam', 'eggs', 'ham', 'monty', ['alpha', 'beta', 'delta', 'gamma']]
>>> access(foo, [4, 7])
['alpha', 'beta', 'delta', 'gamma']
>>> access(foo, [4, 7, 3])
'gamma'
```

If you needed to *assign* to the last element, keep the *last* index aside to then assign to that:

```
if indexes:
    target = access(foo, indexes[:-1])
    target[indexes[-1]] = new_value
else:
    foo = new_value
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set `item` to `foo`, then proceeds with the indexes list to access deeper nested elements:

```
def access (foo, indexes):
    item = foo
    for index in indexes:
        item = item[index]
    return item
```